# Decimate multiple objects at once

Tags: modifiers, objects

I have a scene containing a few hundred objects (meshes). I can decimate one object at a time by selecting it in the scene and add modifier->decimate. Doing this for all objects separately would of course take forever.

How can I decimate all objects at once?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Start by selecting all the objects you want to have the same modifiers applied to.
- Add the decimate modifier to the active object. The active object is the one that is highlighted in a lighter colour than the others, it is also the one that you can alter in the properties window.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and select modifiers. This copies the modifiers from the active object to all other selected objects.

[image]

If you want more control there is an addon called "Copy Attributes Menu" that you can enable (it is included with blender) that allows you to copy selected modifiers.

If you then want to apply the modifier to all objects you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and select Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text, it may sound odd to convert a mesh to a mesh but it applies all modifiers to the selected objects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that applying modifiers trick! Still I think the features like these should be easily accessible via GUI.

Comment: Both the make links and the convert options are available in the object menu of the 3d view header.